# Как реализовать запись звука в браузере на iPhone?

Tags: ios, браузер, аудио

Как реализовать запись звука в браузере на iPhone? Например диктофон который работает через браузер. Все найденные мною решения используют Flash, который на iOS не поддерживается.

Comment: Web Audio Api поддерживается на iOS. Похоже, это даже работает http://typedarray.org/from-microphone-to-wav-with-getusermedia-and-web-audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и есть, взаимодействия с микрофоном и камерой возможны только с использованием flash, который на iOS не поддерживается.